# How to differ inputs with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one Button that duplicates this line to choose more products.
My Html:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" class="cod_linha" name="cod_linha[]"style="width: 100%;" />
    <input type="text" name="linha[]" class="linha" style="width: 100%;" />
</td>
```

The problem is, I have two functions that find the product and other that Fill all the fields that I want automatically, what I have to do to differ this filled field of the empty field ? I tried this:

```
var table = $('#tabelaPedido');
$(table).each(function() {
if($(this).find('input.linha').val()=== ''){
     Executes my function to fill the fields and to add a new line.
}
else{ }
```

And this too :

```
var counter = $(table).find("input.linha").length;
for(var i =0; i < counter; i++){
if($(table).find('input.linha').eq(i).val()== ''{}
```

But those codes don't fill the other empty line. see the imagem :

[image]

My code to fill the fields :

```
function preencherCamposProduto(obj) {
    var table = $('#tabelaPedido');
    $(table).each(function() {
        if($(this).find('input.linha').val()=== '' &&
                $(this).find('input.ref').val()=== '' &&
                $(this).find('input.material').val()=== '' &&
                $(this).find('input.cor').val()=== '' &&
                $(this).find('input.descricao_marca').val()=== ''){
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: '/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/pesquisarCamposProduto',
        async: false,
        data: {
            cd_cpl_tamanho: obj
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var linhaId = data[0].idLinha;
            var linhaLabel = data[0].labelLinha;
            var refId = data[0].idRef;
            var refLabel = data[0].labelRef;
            var corId = data[0].idCor;
            var corLabel = data[0].labelCor;
            var marcaId = data[0].idMarca;
            var marcaLabel = data[0].labelMarca;
            var materialId = data[0].idMaterial;
            var materialLabel = data[0].labelMaterial;`

            var table = $('#tabelaPedido');
            $(table).each(function() {
                $(this).find('input.cod_linha').val(linhaId);
                $(this).find('input.linha').val(linhaLabel);
                $(this).find('input.cod_ref').val(refId);
                $(this).find('input.ref').val(refLabel);
                $(this).find('input.cod_material').val(materialId);
                $(this).find('input.material').val(materialLabel);
                $(this).find('input.cod_cor').val(corId);
                $(this).find('input.cor').val(corLabel);
                $(this).find('input.id_marca').val(marcaId);
                $(this).find('input.descricao_marca').val(marcaLabel);

        });


        }
    });
    chamaAdicionarCampo();
    }else{
        console.log('Entrei no else');
    }
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your code and wrote [a sample code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmnu2hq1/3/), that does things that you are writing about. In my solution I use CSS selector `#tabelaPedido tr:last` to select the last added row, and then write values to fields in this row.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong then... Because when I put this tr:last  my function doesn't fill no one field.. Nothing happens .

Comment: With your answer and the answer of semsem I figure it out.. Now it's working ! I added $( "tr:last" ).find() on my each function and the #table tr:last too... Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The following simple jquery solution may help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.linha').each(function(){  
  if ($(this).val() == ''){
    //Call Your fill input function $(this) as parameter
  }

  });
});
```

Checkout This [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qocuyajone/1/)

Comment: I'm trying to do like this :
`$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.linha').each(function(){  
    if ($(this).val() == ''){
     preencherCamposProduto($(this));
    }
 });`

But I'm getting an error :TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

Comment: @EdsonRodrigues Checkout the demo added to the answer.

Comment: Also you have to note that you have only one table, so it does not need `each`

Comment: Did not worked !  :( ... It fills ok first time, on the next, fills the first and second line...

Comment: It just calls the fill function - what ever is it - for any empty input field with class named `linha` . What do you have to do now, is your fill function itself `preencherCamposProduto`. You have to change its code related to supplying the values returned by AJAX

Comment: @semsem, Now I have to change my code to fill the fields on else?

Comment: @EdsonRodrigues Yes, just make a function that  supplies `obj.val()`  with the value you want. Notice, in this solution the fill function is called several times according to the empty input fields count. Here, you have the input  field as a jquery object, so, `obj` can use jquery methods i.e we can `obj.attr('style','color:red')` .

Comment: Also, Don't forget to add a unique mark for each field, i.e and id attribute for example, to allow your AJAX to get suitable data for it.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer of @zegoline and @semsem I figure it out.. Now it's working ! I added `$( "tr:last" ).find()` to every field on my each function and the `#table tr:last` too... Thanks a lot !